# Efficient handling of super wide, but not so tall, bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap, memory-management

Is there any way to create a more space/resource efficient bitmap?
Currently I try to render a file, approx 800px high but around 720000px wide.
It crashes my application, presumably because of the share memory-size of the bitmap.

Can I do this more efficiently, like creating it as an gif directly and not later when I save it?

I try to save a series of lines/rectangles from a real world reading, and I want it to be 1px per 1/100th of a second.

Comment: For assistance on google open id, check meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You may want to consider storing the data in plain text format, and rendering whatever portion the user requests as an image (with provided export/import functionality).  You might fear this to be more frustrating since the user needs to use your program to work with the data, but working with gigantic images is also hard for users, so you're really in trouble either way.

Comment: I'd love to know why you need such an image.

Answer (score 15):

You have to remember that any image you load into memory regardless if it's a GIF or JPEG or whatever on disk will be turned into a 32 bit bitmap which means four bytes per pixel.

This means that the image you're creating will be:

```
4 bytes * 800 pixels high * 720,000 pixels wide = 2,304,000,000 bytes
```

You're basically blowing your memory by trying to create an image that large.

For whatever you're trying to accomplish the **answer is tiling and caching your image**.

Answer (score 3):

Your image is about 2.3 gig, and the biggest .Net object you can have is 2 gig regardless if the machine is 32 or 64 bit.

You're going to have to break the bitmap up in chunks to handle an image that size.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to either:

- Force x64 environment and get a stack load of RAM.
- Change your architecture

Your image is going to be a little over 2 GB.

Comment: Even switching to x64 will not solve the issue immediately. The maximum object size in the GC Heap is still at 2GB, even in the x64 version of the .NET 2.0 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i do it more efficient, like creating it as an gif directly and not later when i save it?

You can compress the image as you write it. It won't be in (uncompressed/unencoded) "bitmap" format anymore. Examples of compression algorithm include "run-length encoding" and "huffman".

Also, use the least possible color-depth: preferaby black-and-white, i.e. 1-bit-per-pixel.

Also perhaps save it in several, smaller, discontinuous memory chunks: instead of a single huge memory chunk (so huge that it can't even be allocated in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

If you create it as 720000px high and 800px wide as a bmp and rotate it when actually displaying it(*),
you can stream the data directly to file in bitmap form.  Maybe use RLE instead of raw bitmap; streaming in this manner should still be possible in that case.

(*)Displaying it is left as an exercise to the reader.  You'll need tiling or something.