# Encode a Bitmap as a Jpeg

Tags: c#, encoding, bitmap, jpeg

First, this question is NOT about "how to save a Bitmap as a jpeg on your disk?"

I can't find (or think of) a way of converting a `Bitmap` with Jpeg compression, but keep it as a `Bitmap` object. [MSDN clearly shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970689.aspx) how to save a Bitmap as a JPEG, but what I'm looking for is how to apply the encoding/compression to the `Bitmap` object, so I can still pass it around, in my code, without referencing the file.

One of the reasons behind that would be a helper class that handles bitmap, but shouldn't be aware of the persistency method used.

Comment: related to [Compress image in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1377438/11343)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All images are bitmaps when loaded into program memory. Specific compressions are typically utilized when writing to disk, and decompressing when reading from disk.

If you're worried about the in-memory footprint of an image you could zip-compress the bytes and pass the byte array around internally. Zipping would be good for lossless compression of an image. Don't forget that many image compressions have [different levels of losiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) (sp?) In other words, the compression throws away data to store the image in the smallest number of bytes possible.

De/compression is also a performance tradeoff in that you're trading memory footprint for processing time. And in any case, unless you get really fancy, the image does need to be a bitmap if you need to manipulate it in any way.

Here is [an answer for a somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624187/efficient-handling-of-super-wide-but-not-so-tall-bitmap/2624236#2624236) which you might find interesting.

Comment: My concern is really about the separation of concern between the image processing and the persistency. I could be saving the jpeg on a filesystem (direct or isolated storage), in a database, or on the cloud. My image processing doesn't know that, and it wouldn't be right for my persistency layer to do some image processing, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's right. Image processing is a separate concern. Although if you use a lossy compression type of any kind, you are automatically doing processing by throwing data that the compression algorithm think it doesn't need to persist the image.

Answer (score 3):

`Bitmap` does not support encoded in-memory storage. It is always unencoded (see the `PixelFormat` enum). Problably you need to write your own wrapper class/abstraction, or give up on that idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
var stream = new MemoryStream()
Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)
```

Does it what you need?

Comment: Don't forget that jpeg compression is lossy. If you compress to a jpeg and then decompress to bitmap you will have different (less) image information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression